# Eclipse with MinGW does not link correctly

Tags: c, eclipse, linker, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I use the Eclipse Luna IDE for C/C++ (CDT) and MinGW for programming C with Microsoft Windows 7.

I try to write a simple program which uses [KissFFT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/)

This is not directly a library, this are only some *.c and *.h-Files.

My example program is stored at E:\Programming\Programs\Simple_FFT\

That is my example program:

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tools/kiss_fftr.h>

int nfft = 1024;
int inverse_fft = 0;


int main(void) {

 kiss_fftr_cfg cfg = kiss_fftr_alloc(nfft, inverse_fft, NULL, NULL);
 kiss_fft_scalar timedata[nfft]; //input
 kiss_fft_cpx freqdata[nfft]; //output

while (1)
{

 timedata[nfft] = 0;

 kiss_fftr(cfg, timedata, freqdata);

 free(cfg);
}
return 0;
}
```

As you can see I included kiss_fftr.h.
This file on the other hand is including kiss_fft.h.

In Eclipse, I went to Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes -> GNU C -> and there i added the directorys E:\Programming\Libraries\kiss_fft130 and E:\Programming\Libraries\kiss_fft130\tools

Because this are the folders where the needed header files and c files are stored.

So everything fine, not?

But now the curious thing: I can't compile the program with Eclipse. I'm relatively new to programming but as far as I know, if I include a header file and the directory is included in Eclipse, the related *.c-file should be linked automatically.

Instead I get undefinded references:

```html
src\Simple_FFT.o:Simple_FFT.c:(.text.startup+0x3b): undefined reference to `kiss_fftr_alloc'
src\Simple_FFT.o:Simple_FFT.c:(.text.startup+0x86): undefined reference to `kiss_fftr'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: src\Simple_FFT.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
```

The problem is, that Eclipse is not linking the c-files of KissFFT to the included headers.
So I found two solutions to bypass this problem:

First: Compile the program manually:

```html
gcc -o E:\Programming\Programs\Simple_FFT\Release\Simple_FFT -I"E:\Programming\Libraries\kiss_fft130" -I"E:\Programming\Libraries\kiss_fft130\tools" E:\Programming\Programs\Simple_FFT\src\Simple_FFT.c E:\Programming\Libraries\kiss_fft130\tools\kiss_fftr.c E:\Programming\Libraries\kiss_fft130\kiss_fft.c
```

As you can see, I included the *.c-Files "kiss_fftr and kiss_fft" manually and compilation is fine.

Second solution: In Eclipse, I went to Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> MinGW C Linker -> Miscellaneous -> Other Objects -> and added E:\Programming\Libraries\kiss_fft130\kiss_fftr.c and E:\Programming\Libraries\kiss_fft130\kiss_fft.c.

Then the program is compiling fine, too.

Both is not my intention. Because I would have to manually link every *.c-file I use in my program. What is my failure in the properties of Eclipse, that it does not automatically link the correct files together?

Would be very happy to get an answer so I can start programming correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `C` files folders to the `Source Locations` in the `Project Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols`. Or, if you have your `kiss` library compiled (.lib or .a) you should add it in the linker section `Library Search path` and `Libraries`

Comment: If I do this, it wants to link all *.c files which are in the libaries folder to my c-file. Not only the two needed ones I included per header-file. So this gives other problems (because the files aren't designed to link all together.

Why doesn't the linker look for the c-files in the same directory as the h-files (which are in the included directory)?

How can I tell Eclipse that it only needs to link the c-files which have the same name as the header-files I included?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can anybody help? Or is this a common problem if c-files are not designed as a library? Please help me, I'm a beginner!

Comment: In eclipse you can exclude specific source files from the build by right clicking on them end choosing "exclude from build". This is one way. Another would be to use so called " working sets" allowing you to create multiple configurations consisting of which files to be part of the build. Google about "eclipse working sets".

Comment: ah thank you very much. Is it a eclipse specific problem, that the linker/compiler does not look for the *.c-files in the same direction as for the header files or is this behavior normal and I would have to tell every IDE separately where to look for the header files and where for the *.c-files?